# morris.js Multiple stacked bars on single label

Tags: javascript, html, graph, morris.js

I'm curious if morris.js supports having multiple stacked bars on single label and if someone knows workaround.

[image]

I want to have 2 graphs stacked together on same line. Blue and red should be on top each other and green and yellow.

[image]

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'daily_revenue',
    data: [],
    xkey: 'label',
    ykeys: ['inbound_netto', 'inbound_brutto', 'outbound_netto', 'outbound_brutto'],
    labels: ['Inbound Netto', 'Inbound Brutto', 'Outbound Netto', 'Outbound Brutto'],
    resize: true,
    barColors: ["#B21516", "#1531B2", "#1AB244", "#B29215"],
    hideHover: true
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible with the latest Morris.js version (0.5.1). 
You can set the `stacked` parameter to true in your `Morris.Bar` configuration, but for only one stacked bar for each label:

```
stacked: true
```

[Morris charts samples](http://codepen.io/andreic/pen/CJoze)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But i already tried this and it is not what i am looking for. If i use stacked: true it puts all 4 graphs that are on one label together and i dont want that. I want to have 2 stacked graphs on 1 label. I want to have multiple stacked bar charts per per label.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. I guess i should find some alternative to Morris.js, that support that functionality. I was using jpgraph that support this, but then i switched to js graphs.

Comment: Instead of morris.js i rather choosed highcharts. It has all those functionality and much more.

Comment: There's also [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/). You can also validate my answer if you're up to it ^_^